# Sending Commands to tmux Running in tmux

Tags: unix, ssh, tmux

I'm using `tmux` to manage my windows, etc, and one of the things I do is SSH to a remote server and connect to a tmux session running there. Once there, however, I cannot sent C-b through to that tmux session (the one running in ssh in my original, local tmux).

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> once for the local `tmux` and again for the remote one, then the key for the command you want to use on the remote session.

Comment: Alternatively, change the prefix key for the tmux you've SSH'd into, and you don't have to hit anything twice.

Answer (score 2):

#### If you haven't mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>

If you haven't mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to last-window to emulate screen's behavior (which is quite popular), then you can use that as your prefix for the inner tmux session.  So to issue commands to the inner session you would use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> *Command*

*The above answer assumes your prefix key is still <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> on both machines.*

#### If you have mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>

If you have mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, then you'll need to use tmux's `:send-prefix` command.  Many people map this to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> to emulate screen's default behavior.  You would add this to your .tmux.conf to add this binding permanently:
`bind b send-prefix`

Then you can issue commands to the inner session using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> *Command*
(or without the binding using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> `:send-prefix` *Command*)

*The above answer assumes your prefix key is still <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> on the outer session.*

Answer (score 0):

In short you can add the following line into your tmux.conf to control "tmux inside tmux". This line define your bind key to  `CTRL+A` for the "remote" session.

```
bind-key -n C-a send-prefix
```

The shortcut `C-a` can be change by any other free keys.

Then you can use `CTRL+B`to control you tmux session level1 (default) and 
`CTRL+A`to control the second tmux session.